# How can I change the value of int to dp and px?

Tags: int, pixel

I want to convert a value of int to dp , pixel. How can I do that? Help me! Thanks

Comment: Comparing oranges to apples (once again) -- "int" and "pixel"... In what sense? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I think it's `in`ches.

Comment: This is an "XY problem".

Answer (score 0):

The relation between distances and pixels is the resolution of the display. Depending on what you are trying to do, there is either an interface you can use to query this, or (in CSS, which I assume you are using) you are expected to use what is more appropriate and not assume anything.

If you require the output to have a specific size, independent of the display size, use `cm` or `in`. You'd only use that in few cases, such as when displaying fincancial transaction data for reading by a card reader.

For a somewhat fixed relationship between text and image size, use the `em` (size of a capital M) and `ex` (size of a lowercase x) units. This is almost always what you want, as it deals gracefully with users increasing the text size because they have a high-resolution display (or bad vision).

Lastly, if the number of pixels is important, use `px`.

The `dp` unit is similar in behaviour to to the `cm` and `in` units, but doesn't require fractions for small sizes, which makes it a bit easier to use.